# GitPython to get Github repositories status

Tags: raspberry-pi, gitpython

I am working on a project where I want to get the status of my private Github repository using python and as per the status I want blink the LED on the raspberry pi3 module...For example if the commit is failed then LED turns red and if commit is successful then LED turn green..

I see there is an option using gitpython but I don't the working usage of it.. Can someone help me on how to implement it

Comment: Try to divide your question into parts and try to solve the smaller parts first. Are you able to get the status of your git repository? Are you able to blink the led?

Comment: I am able to blink the led but I am stuck with git repo status...How do I achieve that using either API's or gitpython...

Comment: Next step, find and read the documentation for the package you re trying to use and try to write some code for it, when the code fails return here with the question.